# 3 node cluster with crossover cables

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, storage-spaces, cluster-shared-volumes

We have a windows failover cluster running Windows 2012 R2 for Hyper-V.  Our storage is using Storage Spaces with a SAS3 JBOD.  As such, we see IO transfers hitting 2800 MBps.  Our networking is still on Gigabit LACP links, severly limiting speeds accessing CSV disks.

If node 2 owns the CSV, node 1 will max out at 114 MBps in sequential reads.  Node 2 will continue to read and write at 2800 MBps.

[image: diagram of current configuration]

Can we use a mesh of six 10 Gbps Ethernet cards (without a switch) to create a full mesh for CSV and Live migration traffic?  Will this validate?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that will work. However, it won't be crossover. Use straight cables, as crossover isn't used since 1GB ethernet. All you should have to do is use two NICs on each box to contact all others, and assign them all different IPs.

Use entries in the hosts file of each machine to organize the addresses, realizing that each metal will have two addresses for this 10G network, yet server A will connect to server B on a different IP than server A will connect to server C (and so on). Using the hosts file will keep it organized by referring to different IPs for other hosts depending on which one you're "looking" at.

Only other thing is, this obviously won't scale well. Buy it's also really easy to tear down.